# Copy duplicate values from one column to a separate sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, countif

I have a list of names in one column in sheetA. I want to copy the duplicate names from sheet A to sheet B and also provide a count of those duplicate names beside each copied name in sheet B.

Comment: What have you tried? Also, what do you want to achieve this in? I'm guessing it's not manually; VBA?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific.

I want to have it automated. Either formula or VBA. Essentially I have a list in one sheet. I need the duplicate names in the list to be copied to a second list and also a count of the number of times these names appeared in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m guessing it is ‘manually’ so would suggest a helper column in sheetA with `=COUNTIF(A:A,A1)` copied down (assuming your list of names starts in A1. For each row this should count the number of rows that contain that row’s name.
Copy ColumnA:B into your sheetB with Paste Special Values, then use Data > Data Tools – Remove Duplicates and filter and delete all rows with `1` in the count column.

Comment: Thats helpful. I was wondering if there is a formula/macro so that it can be automated?

Answer (score 0):

easiest method I can think of would be a pivot table, rows=names, columns=count of names, filter table for counts greater than 0?  then when you want to run a fresh report, past in the original information and refresh the table?

Probably way too late to be helpful, but maybe for the next person...